# Handling different date formats in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am trying to build a ROR app that allows users to enter date in various formats such as 12/31/11 (month/day/year) or 31/12/11 (day/month/year). In order to interpret date format, I will have a select field from where user can select the format of date. I can use  `Date.strptime(value, format).to_s()` in controller before saving record.

However, I am not sure is controller right place to put this information. Is there a way I can push this to model..say in before save method.

Answer (score 0):

You could just save the data as it is (in the controller), and have another field in the model telling it how to interpret the data. Then, in a before_validation callback, you could try parsing the date according to the given format and writing it to the same field, now as a date. Problems may arise on the way back. Then, to display it in the view again, you could write helpers - but better yet, provide a method in the model (for instance, formatted_date) that will compute and display the date.

However, this requirement sounds strange. Why is the user's responsibility to select a date format? Shouldn't it be based on the user locale?

In any case, I suggest you register your date formats in an initializer, rather than repeting the format strings throughout the application.